# I can't find the error within my dynamic sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, dynamic-sql, sql-server-2014

I have a problem with the stored procedure code below, it runs smoothly but as I try to execute the store procedure, it throws this error:

> Msg 241, Level 16, State 1, Procedure ACC_ARAP_DOC_LIST, Line 27
>   Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

I'm guessing its `@DATE_FROM` and `@DATE_TO`? From outside its declared as `DATETIME` format. When executing the stored procedure, I tried both `2001-01-01` and `01-01-2001` format. Both threw out the same error.
I'm using SQL Server 2014 Management Studio.

So does anyone know where the problem lies?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ACC_ARAP_DOC_LIST]
    @DATE_FROM DATETIME,
    @DATE_TO DATETIME,
    @DOC_TYPE_GROUP CHAR(20)='DIV',
    @FILTER_CONDITION NVARCHAR(4000)='',
    @RESULT_MODE NVARCHAR(30)= NULL --'DOC_SUM'
AS
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(4000) --Select
    DECLARE @SQL2 NVARCHAR(4000)
    DECLARE @WHERE NVARCHAR(4000)
    DECLARE @PARAMETER NVARCHAR(1000)
    DECLARE @GROUP_BY NVARCHAR(4000)
    DECLARE @GROUP_ORDER_BY NVARCHAR(4000)
    DECLARE @ORDER_BY NVARCHAR(4000)
    DECLARE @SQL_SUM_START NVARCHAR(4000)
    DECLARE @SQL_SUM_END NVARCHAR(4000)

    SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM (SELECT j1.journal_no, j1.acc_date, j1.partner_code, j1.term_code, j1.due_date, j1.ref_no1, j1.ref_no2,
                                j1.description,j1.sales_person,j1.pay_remark ,j1.amount,j1.acc_amount,j1.currency, j1.match_acc_amount, p1.name as partner_name
                                FROM acc_journal j1 
                                INNER JOIN acc_journal_groupcfg g1 ON g1.group_type=''LST'' AND g1.doc_type_group=' + @DOC_TYPE_GROUP + ' AND g1.doc_type=j1.doc_type
                                LEFT OUTER JOIN partner p1 ON j1.partner_code=p1.partner_code 
                                LEFT OUTER JOIN partner_acc p2 ON p1.partner_id=p2.partner_id) as sql1'
    SET @WHERE = ' WHERE acc_date>=' + @DATE_FROM +' AND acc_date<=' + @DATE_TO + ' ' +
       (CASE WHEN ISNULL(@filter_condition,'')<>'' 
                    THEN 'AND '+@filter_condition ELSE '' END)
    SET @ORDER_BY = ' ORDER BY journal_no'

    SET @PARAMETER = '@DATE_FROM DATETIME,@DATE_TO DATETIME,@RESULT_MODE NVARCHAR(30)=''DOC_SUM'',@DOC_TYPE_GROUP CHAR(20)'


    SET @SQL = @SQL + @WHERE + @ORDER_BY

    IF @RESULT_MODE = 'DOC_SUM'
    BEGIN
        SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM (SELECT j1.journal_no, j1.acc_date, j1.partner_code as Code, j1.term_code, j1.due_date, j1.ref_no1, j1.ref_no2,
                                j1.description,j1.sales_person,j1.pay_remark ,j1.amount,j1.acc_amount,j1.currency, j1.match_acc_amount, p1.name as Name
                                FROM acc_journal j1 
                                INNER JOIN acc_journal_groupcfg g1 ON g1.group_type=''LST'' AND g1.doc_type_group=' +@DOC_TYPE_GROUP +'AND g1.doc_type=j1.doc_type
                                LEFT OUTER JOIN partner p1 ON j1.partner_code=p1.partner_code 
                                LEFT OUTER JOIN partner_acc p2 ON p1.partner_id=p2.partner_id) as sql1'
        SET @SQL_SUM_START= 'SELECT Code, Name, COUNT(*) as Count, SUM(acc_amount) as Total_Amount FROM ('
        SET @SQL_SUM_END= ') as SQLsum'

        SET @GROUP_BY = ' GROUP BY Code, Name'
        SET @GROUP_ORDER_BY = ' ORDER BY Code, Name'
        SET @SQL2 = @SQL_SUM_START + @SQL +@SQL_SUM_END + @GROUP_BY + @GROUP_ORDER_BY
    END

    SET @SQL = 'SELECT * FROM (SELECT j1.journal_no, j1.acc_date, j1.partner_code, j1.term_code, j1.due_date, j1.ref_no1, j1.ref_no2,
                                j1.description,j1.sales_person,j1.pay_remark ,j1.amount,j1.acc_amount,j1.currency, j1.match_acc_amount, p1.name as partner_name
                                FROM acc_journal j1 
                                INNER JOIN acc_journal_groupcfg g1 ON g1.group_type=''LST'' AND g1.doc_type_group=' + @DOC_TYPE_GROUP +'AND g1.doc_type=j1.doc_type
                                LEFT OUTER JOIN partner p1 ON j1.partner_code=p1.partner_code 
                                LEFT OUTER JOIN partner_acc p2 ON p1.partner_id=p2.partner_id) as sql1'
    SET @SQL = @SQL + @WHERE + @ORDER_BY

    EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, @SQL2, @PARAMETER,
    @DOC_TYPE_GROUP=@DOC_TYPE_GROUP,
    @DATE_FROM=@DATE_FROM,
    @DATE_TO=@DATE_TO
END
```

Comment: which dbms you r using and whats the value coming in Date_from and date_to

Comment: Try the ISO-8601 date format: `YYYYMMDD` - no dashes, no spaces - nothing. And if you only need the date anyway (no time) - use the `DATE` datatype instead!

Comment: I use MSSQL and the value is usually '2014-01-01' and '2015-12-31'.

Comment: @marc_s I got this error: Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Procedure ACC_ARAP_DOC_LIST, Line 32
The data types varchar and date are incompatible in the add operator.

Answer (score 0):

In you stored procedure should be concat two variable `@DATE_FROM` and `@DATE_TO`. It must be convert `varchar`. Like this

```
SET @WHERE = ' WHERE acc_date>=' +convert(varchar(25), @DATE_FROM )+' AND acc_date<=' +convert(varchar(25), @DATE_TO) + ' ' +
```

remove this code

```
 (CASE WHEN ISNULL(@filter_condition,'')<>'' 
                    THEN 'AND '+@filter_condition ELSE '' END)
```

Replace

```
if(isnull(@FILTER_CONDITION,'')!='')
     SET @WHERE=@WHERE+'AND '+@filter_condition
```

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near '1'.

Comment: Add calling store procedure data

Comment: EXEC return_value = [dbo].[ACC_ARAP_DOC_LIST]
  DATE_FROM = N'2001-01-01',
  DATE_TO = N'2015-12-31',
  DOC_TYPE_GROUP = N'DIV',
  RESULT_MODE = NULL --N'DOC_SUM'

SELECT 'Return Value' = return_value

GO

Comment: Just see this part -> DATE_FROM = N'2001-01-01', DATE_TO = N'2015-12-31'

Answer (score 0):

You need to CONVERT your DATETIME parameters to suitable strings where you intend to build theminto your dynamic SQL strings. For example, instead of:

```
... 
SET @WHERE = ' WHERE acc_date>=' + @DATE_FROM +' AND acc_date<=' + @DATE_TO + ' ' +...
```

use (note the extra quotes)

```
...
SET @WHERE = ' WHERE acc_date>=''' + CONVERT(nvarchar(30), @DATE_FROM, 120) 
+ ''' AND acc_date<=''' + CONVERT(nvarchar(30), @DATE_TO, 120) + ''' ' + ...
```

also, you need to quote your @DOC_TYPE_GROUP parameter in the built up string as follows (again, note the extra quotes):

```
...AND g1.doc_type_group=''' + @DOC_TYPE_GROUP + ''' AND g1.doc_type=...
```

and I advise you to `PRINT @SQL` instead of `SP_EXEC SQL @SQL` to help your debugging.

Comment: @DATE_FROM='2001-01-01' and @DATE_TO='2015-12-31' then I got this error: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near '00'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert the values from `@date_from` and `@date_to` to an `NVARCHAR`. After that you need to set parentheses around it.

Replace this:

```
SET @WHERE = ' WHERE acc_date>=' + @DATE_FROM +' AND acc_date<=' + @DATE_TO + '
```

With this:

```
SET @WHERE = ' WHERE acc_date>=''' + CONVERT(nvarchar(max),@DATE_FROM) +''' AND acc_date<=''' + CONVERT(nvarchar(max),@DATE_TO) + '''
```

By the way, you should raise your `@sql` value too, to avoid some cutoff errors.
You use `nvarchar(4000)` for `@sql`. Instead try to use `nvarchar(max)`. It may avoid errors if your SQL may get lengthy.